# Import xml with Feeds from a folder outside site directory

Tags: feeds

I need to import data from multiple xml files. my site is in **/var/www/sites/automationstats** and the folder with the data is in subfolders of **/var/lib/jenkins**

If I use as directory in the import **/var/lib**, I get this error message: Directory needs to be a valid URI.

By the way, that folder (/var/lib) has owner and group **jenkins**. My first idea was to set that folder in the file system settings as private and then use **private://** as URI but it says the folder is not writable.

So, is it possible to read from outside my site file structure or I have to get the files inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you were right the correct way is to add in file system configuration (/admin/config/media/file-system) a private file system path that you need "*/var/lib/jenkins*", and then use it in your feed fetcher with prefix **private://**.

Please if it is possible move yor files form /var/lib to a user subfolder to avoid security problems.